# Elegant use of arrays in ksh

Tags: arrays, variables, ksh

I'm trying build an sort of property set in ksh.

Thought the easiest way to do so was using arrays but the syntax is killing me.

What I want is to

1. Build an arbitrary sized array in a config file with a name and a property.
2. Iterate for each item in that list and get that property.

I theory what I wish I could do is something like

```
MONITORINGSYS={
    SYS1={NAME="GENERATOR" MONITORFUNC="getGeneratorStatus"}
    SYS2={NAME="COOLER" MONITORFUNC="getCoolerStatus"}
}
```

Then later on, be able to do something like:

```
for CURSYS in $MONITORINGSYS
do
    CSYSNAME=$CURSYS.NAME
    CSYSFUNC=$CURSYS.MONITORFUNC

    REPORT="$REPORT\n$CSYSNAME"

    CSYSSTATUS=CSYSFUNC $(date)
    REPORT="$REPORT\t$CSYSSTATUS"
done
echo $REPORT
```

Well, that's not real programming, but I guess you got the point..

How do I do that?

**[EDIT]**

I do not mean I want to use associative arrays. I only put this way to make my question more clear... I.e. It would not be a problem if the loop was something like:

```
for CURSYS in $MONITORINGSYS
do
    CSYSNAME=${CURSYS[0]}
    CSYSFUNC=${CURSYS[1]}

    REPORT="$REPORT\n$CSYSNAME"

    CSYSSTATUS=CSYSFUNC $(date)
    REPORT="$REPORT\t$CSYSSTATUS"
done
echo $REPORT
```

Same applies to the config file.. I'm just looking for a syntax that makes it minimally readable.

cheers

Comment: Not in ksh. ksh arrays are integer-based only -- at least for the ksh implementations I have access to. I'm sure you could hack something together with clever strings you can parse, but if you want associative arrays, pick a language with associative arrays.

Comment: This is definitely doable with post ksh88m versions. Sorry I don't have time to give you an example right now. Look at kornshell.com, get the UWIN version. `set -A myArr` will get you started. I have seen reports on the UWIN mailing list of people having multi-megabyte variables, more complex than you describe. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, but the arrays do not need to be associative. I only explained that way to make it clear.. I wouldn't mind accessing lets say ``CSYSNAME=CURSYS [0]`` and ``CSYSFUNC=CURSYS [1]`` in the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you want... Kornshell can handle both associative and indexed arrays.

However, Kornshell arrays are one dimensional. It might be possible to use indirection to emulate a two dimensional array via the use of `$()` and eval. I did this a couple of times in the older Perl 4.x and Perl 3.x, but it's a pain. If you want multidimensional arrays, use Python or Perl.

The only thing is that you must declare arrays via the `typedef` command:

```
$ typeset -A foohash    #foohash is an associative array
$ typeset -a foolist    #foolist is an integer indexed array.
```

Maybe your script can look something like this

```
typeset -a sysname
typeset -a sysfunct

sysname[1] = "GENERATOR"
sysname[2] = "COOLER"
sysfunc[1] = "getGeneratorStatus"
sysfunc[2] = "getCoolerStatus"

for CURSYS in {1..2}
do
   CSYSNAME="${sysname[$CURSYS]}"
   CSYSFUNC="${sysfunc[$CURSYS]}"
   REPORT="$REPORT\n$CSYSNAME"
   CSYSSTATUS=$(eval "CSYSFUNC $(date)")
   REPORT="$REPORT\t$CSYSSTATUS"
done
echo $REPORT
```

Comment: Very interesting. I was not aware of ``-A`` for associative arrays, but it might be just what I need. Is there a way I can get the index name? say, ``typeset -A foo; foo["COOLER"]="getCoolerStatus"`` and somehow later, I could get the word ``"COOLER"`` from ``foo`` as well? thanks!

Comment: meh... apparently my ksh does not support ``-A``.. The version is ``Version M-11/16/88f`` (An AIX box).

Comment: Version 88 should support associative arrays because it was mentioned in David Korn's original book from AT&T. (I have a signed copy!). I looked on my system, and mine is 93, so I can't test it. Type "typeset -h" and see what it prints out. Ksh 93 adds a tk type graphics layer, and the ability to handle floating and compound variables. It was an attempt to make Kornshell a full programming language, but never really took off.

Answer (score 3):

ksh93 now has compound variables which can contain a mixture of indexed and associative arrays.  No need to declare it as ksh will work it out itself.

```sh
#!/bin/ksh

MONITORINGSYS=(
        [SYS1]=(NAME="GENERATOR" MONITORFUNC="getGeneratorStatus")
        [SYS2]=(NAME="COOLER" MONITORFUNC="getCoolerStatus")
)

echo MONITORING REPORT
echo "-----------------"

for sys in ${!MONITORINGSYS[*]}; do
        echo "System:    $sys"
        echo "Name:      ${MONITORINGSYS[$sys].NAME}"
        echo "Generator: ${MONITORINGSYS[$sys].MONITORFUNC}"
        echo
done
```

Output:

```
MONITORING REPORT
-----------------
System:    SYS1
Name:      GENERATOR
Generator: getGeneratorStatus

System:    SYS2
Name:      COOLER
Generator: getCoolerStatus
```

Comment: What's wrong with this assignment? 
typeset -C xxx
xxx.NAME=GENERATOR
xxx.MONITORFUNC=getFooBar
typeset -A MONITORINGSYS
MONITORINGSYS[SYS1]=$xxx
(or xxx)
This prints out empty name and generator.. 
Thanks

Comment: Try this: `typeset -C MONITORINGSYS[SYS1]=xxx`, _without_ using `typeset -A MONITORINGSYS`.

Comment: Yes thanks I realized that as well, but could not find this example anywhere. Thanks again